# OpenCV Image Stitching - using ExposureCompensator and MultiabandBlender class

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, panoramas, image-stitching

I am working a panoramic stitching project and I am trying to implement M. Brown and D. Lowe's [Automatic Panoramic Image Stitching using Invariant Features](http://matthewalunbrown.com/papers/ijcv2007.pdf) by tweaking and adapting it to my needs. I understand the OpenCV stitching method in stitcher class is based on this.

I am stuck at the gain compensation and multi-band blending part. While I understand the theory behind it fairly well, I am shaky on the implementation.

OpenCV has classes for both, [ExposureCompensator](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/exposure_compensation.html) and [MultibandBlender](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/blenders.html) but I am struggling to put them to use in code.

Has anyone sucessfully used any of these classes ? Are there any good examples ?

While I was googling, I came across

1. [Balancing contrast and brightness between stitched images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978689/balancing-contrast-and-brightness-between-stitched-images)

This tries to explain roughly how to use ExposureCompesator but does not explain what the inputs are. Specifically, the inputs for feed method are `vector<Point>` corners and `Vector<Mat>` masks.

a) What are these corners ? Are these the top left corners of the individual images in the final panorama ? or something else ?

b) What are the masks ? How should I create them ?

2. [How to use Multi-band Blender in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044477/how-to-use-multi-band-blender-in-opencv)

This tries to explain how to use the blender class but again misses the input definitions. What are the corners and masks ?

This is my stitched panorama, I am trying to compensate the exposure differences and blend it. 
[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I have the same exact problem...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the [official tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html) under the section `Stitching detailed (python opencv >4.0.1)`. There you have a detailed implementation within both C++ and Python where also compensation and blending is included!